# Determining source tables / columns from SELECT

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to determine the source tables / columns for a particular query?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.GetFullName
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFullName
(
    @FirstName nVARCHAR(100),
    @MiddleName nVARCHAR(100),
    @LastName nVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS nVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN RTRIM(CONCAT(@FirstName, ' ' + @MiddleName, ' ', @LastName))

END
GO

SELECT
    dbo.GetFullName(pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName),
    IIF(PATINDEX('%[ ][0-9]%', pp.Address) > 0, RTRIM(LEFT(pp.Address, PATINDEX('%[ ][0-9]%', pp.Address))), NULL) As Street,
    IIF(PATINDEX('%[ ][0-9]%', pp.Address) > 0, SUBSTRING(pp.Address, PATINDEX('%[ ][0-9]%', pp.Address) + 1, 10), NULL) As HouseNumber,
    pt.Name As PetName
FROM People pp
LEFT JOIN Pets pt ON pt.PeopleID = pp.ID
```

The output that I'm aiming for:

```
TableName       ColumnName
-----------------------------------------
People          FirstName
People          MiddleName
People          LastName
People          Address
Pets            Name
```

I'm looking for something that supports complex scenarios objects nested in objects, nested in other objects etc.

Comment: Hi Koen. Can you also mention in your question why you would need this information?

Comment: To invoke a very precise "changed-data" event on (dynamic) datasets (SELECT queries) that spreads across multiple tables and even might include "helper"-objects such as views or functions

Comment: AFAICT there is no trivial functionality that goes into detail like that, i.e. funtionality that analyses the query structure to list those details. You could go delve into execution plans and analyze those. Should be possible I think (that's too deep for me, haven't delved into that). I also think that is a very complex undertaking that is probably much more effort than it's worth.